# Given is a list with $18$ entries. How many sequences are possible under this certain condition?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Given is a list (of most visited websites). In total we have $18$ 
>   entries. How many different sequences are possible where Google is
>   never at the top?
>
> ```
> Google
> YouTube
> Facebook
> Baidu
> Wikipedia
> Yahoo!
> Reddit
> Google India
> Tencent QQ
> Taobao
> Amazon
> Tmall
> Twitter
> Google Japan
> Sohu
> Windows Live
> VK
> Instagram
> ```

I'm confused how this could be solved correctly. So if we were just looking for all possible entries without any special condition, we would simply calculate $18! = 6.4023737e+15$, right?

But with this condition where `Google` may never be at the first position, it's not as easy.

I think we can keep $18!$ in mind but add a restriction, that condition. I don't have any reasonable explanation but what about $(18-1)!=3.5568743e+14$ possibilities ?

Even if I'm correct which I doubt, I hope you can explain in detail how you solve it? I have trouble in understanding this topic.

Comment: Is "Google never at the top" supposed to also prohibit Google India and Google Japan?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen No, just "Google". No more or less characters :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT**

How many possible ways you could have if you fix "Google" as the top one?

Then you subtract/exclude it.

Comment: So I firstly calculate the total possibilities of $18$ entries which I already did. Then I calculate the total possibilities of the $18$ entries where Google is always at the top. Then I take the total possibilities and subtract with the other (where Google is always at the top). This will be my result if I got you correctly? Sadly I don't know how that second calculation is done but I will post another comment when I know.

Comment: @cnmesr yep, you are right! And for possibilities when Google is always at the top, could you see it is just arranging a group of websites that does not have Google?

Comment: "And for possibilities when Google is always at the top, could you see it is just arranging a group of websites that does not have Google?" does that mean $17!$? So the solution would be $18!-17!$ ?

Comment: @cnmesr Yep, you got it :)

Comment: Thank you very much :D Anyway this is tough logic for me, can't wait for the exam :p

Comment: @cnmesr you are welcome. And good luck for your exam!